# How can i use localStorage to maintain state after a page refresh in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Each time a user logs in, i want the state to remain at 'true' even if there is a page reload. 
The state is set initially to false,  (let _authed = false).
But when i reload the page, it goes back to false, which is the index page.

**What i did**
When the user logs in, i save the user's details in localStorage and when the user logs out, i cleared the localStorage and i set it to false. (this works fine)

In the setAuthed() function, i tried to check if the user i stored in localStorage is not null, it should keep the authed variable to true.

But its not working when i refresh the page. Is there anything, i am doing wrong? Help appreciated.

```
let _authed = false;

// User logs in, set user in localStorage
saveUser(user){
  _user = user;
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
},

//User clicks logout, set state to false 
setLogout(){
  _authed = false;
  localStorage.clear()
},

 // If there is a user in local storage, always set state to true
setAuthed(){
     if (localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
      _authed = true;
      }
},


getAuthed(){
  return _authed;
},
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setAuthed`?

Comment: Where is the actual React code that calls these functions? And where do these functions live? (hopefully not global scope but some library object that you're importing/requiring for your React component(s)?)

Comment: Its actually a flux architecture and the code resides in the store

Answer (score 2):

You can use `React lifecycle` methods to read and write some kind of persistent state. Here I've wrote a tiny example to show it.

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  }
  
  componentDidMount () {
    const persistState = localStorage.getItem('rootState');
    
    if (persistState) {
      try {
        this.setState(JSON.parse(persistState));
      } catch (e) {
        // is not json
      }
    }
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount () {
    localStorage.setItem('rootState', JSON.stringify(this.state);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer has the right ideas but it won't work as is. `persistState` is spelled three different ways, and it's `localStorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem`. More importantly `componentWillUnmount` won't get a chance to run before a window reload. You have to use the `beforeunload` handler or better yet just store the token or whatever as soon as you get it.