# Make localStorage retain its content on page refresh in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add a favorite page to my application, which basically will list some of the previously inserted data. I want the data to be fetched from localStorage. It essentially works, but when I navigate to another page and come back, the localStorage is empty again. I want the data in localStorage to persist when the application is refreshed.

The data is set to localStorage from here

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react'
export const CombinationContext = createContext();

const CombinationContextProvider = (props) => {
let [combination, setCombination] = useState({
    baseLayer: '',
    condiment: '',
    mixing: '',
    seasoning: '',
    shell: ''
});
const saveCombination = (baseLayer, condiment, mixing, seasoning, shell) => {
    setCombination(combination = { baseLayer: baseLayer, condiment: condiment, mixing: mixing, seasoning: seasoning, shell: shell });
}
let [combinationArray, setCombinationArray] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    combinationArray.push(combination);
    localStorage.setItem('combinations', JSON.stringify(combinationArray));
}, [combination]);
return (
    <CombinationContext.Provider value={{combination, saveCombination}}>
        { props.children }
    </CombinationContext.Provider>
);
}

export default CombinationContextProvider;
```

And fetched from here

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { NavContext } from '../contexts/NavContext';

const Favorites = () => {
let { toggleNav } = useContext(NavContext);
let [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(localStorage.getItem('combinations'));
console.log(favorites);
return (
    <div className="favorites" >
        <img className="menu" src={require("../img/tacomenu.png")} onClick={toggleNav} />
        <div className="favorites-title">YOUR FAVORITES</div>
        <div>{ favorites }</div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Favorites;
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111159/how-can-i-use-localstorage-to-maintain-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the local storage with empty data before you load the data from local storage. Familiarize yourself with React's [component lifecycle](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-lifecycle-methods/) in order to ensure you're calling the getItem and setItem methods at the right time in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.  This code block:

```
useEffect(() => {
    combinationArray.push(combination);
    localStorage.setItem('combinations', JSON.stringify(combinationArray));
}, [combination]);
```

Will run any time the dependency array `[combination]` changes, which includes the first render.  The problem with this is `combination` has all empty values on the first render so it is overwriting your local storage item.

Also, `combinationArray.push(combination);` is not going to cause a rerender because you are just changing a javascript value so react doesn't know state changed.  You should use the updater function react gives you, like this:

`setCombinationArray(prevArr => [...prevArr, combination])`

You should push to your `combinationArray` and set the result as the new state value and be careful not to overwrite your old local storage values